# Directional limits of $\frac{ax + y + by^2}{\sin y + \ln (1+x)}$ when $(x,y) \to (0,0)$

Tags: limits

I have to determine a and b such that all directional limits of the function are the same. Then i have to prove that for those a and b, the limit does not exist.
This is what i have done, but im not sure if its ok. 
(Polar coordinates)
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac {ax + y + by^2}{\sin y + \ln (1+x)}=\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{a r \cos \theta+r\sin\theta+br^2\sin^2\theta}{\sin(r\sin\theta)+\ln(1+r\cos\theta)}$$
Then i use equivalents
$$\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{a r \cos \theta+r\sin\theta+br^2\sin^2\theta}{\sin(r\sin\theta)+\ln(1+r\cos\theta)}=\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{r(a\cos\theta+\sin\theta+br\sin^2\theta)}{r\sin\theta+r\cos\theta}=\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{a\cos\theta+\sin\theta+br\sin^2\theta}{\sin\theta+\cos\theta}$$
But im not sure either this is right or not, and how to continue.
Thanks!

Comment: Hint: What you showed is that the directional limit along every angle $\theta$ such that $\sin\theta+\cos\theta\ne0$ exists and is $\frac{a\cos\theta+\sin\theta}{\sin\theta+\cos\theta}$. Now you want that the directional limit also exists when $\sin\theta+\cos\theta=0$. If you reuse your computations in this case, you should see some conditions on $(a,b)$ pop up. Can you do that?

Comment: Thanks! Should be a=1 and b any number? I know that if $\theta = 3\pi/4$ then $\lim_{\theta \to 3\pi/4} \frac{a\cos\theta+\sin\theta}{\cos\theta+\sin\theta}=\infty$, that if a is not 1. Is this ok?

Comment: By "$\theta=3\pi/4$" i meant that when $\theta=3\pi/4$, then $\cos\theta+\sin\theta=0$, so $\lim_{\theta \to 3\pi/4} \cos\theta+\sin\theta=0$

Comment: "Is this ok?" No. You are not interested in the limit when $\theta\to3\pi/4$ in your comment but in the limit, for $\theta=3\pi/4$ (and then, for $\theta=7\pi/4$), of the function in your question when $r\to0$.

Comment: Sorry, but if i do the  $\lim_{(r,\theta) \to (0, 3\pi/4)} \frac{a \cos\theta+\sin\theta+br\sin^2\theta}{\cos\theta+\sin\theta}$, does not $\lim_{(r,\theta) \to (0,3\pi/4)} br\sin^2\theta=0$ for every b? and whats left is $lim_{(r,\theta) \to (0,3\pi/4)} \frac{a \cos\theta+\sin\theta}{\sin\theta+\cos\theta}$?

Comment: No. Please see previous comment (and possibly check the definition of "directional limit").